# How to integrate 2 APIs

Tags: api, asp.net-core, .net-core, integration

I have 2 APIs need to be integrated so the data will be pulled from one API using the GET method and post to the other API using the POST method.

Both APIs use the same authentication mechanism and accept JSON objects.

What is the best way to achieve this goal with less effort and best results using .net core?

Can a custom middleware help in this case?

Comment: Yes, Thank you for your input.

Comment: Think of middleware as a transformation mechanism. Each middleware transforms part of input or output. So, No. Middleware won't help here.
Also, you should always keep you APIs clean. A GET method should only GET and never POST. So, your ask of get should post something somewhere is incorrect. 
Provide the problem/situation you are trying to solve to get better guidance here.

Comment: What can help here?

Comment: How do you plan to use invoke this functionality?

Comment: The [Middleware](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-6.0) is software that's assembled into an app pipeline to handle requests and responses. For your problem to transfer data between the two APIs, I think it is better to [create a Background tasks with hosted services in ASP.NET Core](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio), in the task, you could consume an api to get the data, then call another api to push data. And you can also run it at once or runs on a timer.

Comment: What is your tech stack beside the .net core? Where are you hosting your services? Are you using some cloud? What other components are you using (Azure Functions / RabbitMQ / etc.)? Background tasks mentioned by Zhi Lv are ok, but maybe you can plug in them into some existing architecture